# cxdbimage - show a bigger picture

Tags: delphi, devexpress

cxDbImage loads a picture from database. Kind of thumbnail.

How can I have this pictures shown a little bigger out of the cxdbimage
container when I click on the picture inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some projects that use this kind of functionality. I simply have created a form with a TcxImage inside (align alClient).
Then, on cxDbImage DbClick event, I just perform something like this:

```
  FMyForm := TMyForm.Create(Self);
  try
    FMyForm.cxImage1.Picture := cxDBImage1.Picture;
    FMyForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FMyForm);
  end;
```

If I understood your question correctly, this approach can help you.